# Only IE will correctly run my PHP/ MySQL query!

Tags: php, mysql, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

One of my PHP files executes a query that inserts a record into my database. Here is the code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO conversations (viID, moID, viTyping, moTyping, priority, status, open, mOpen, lastMsgID, searched) VALUES ('1999', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 'yahh')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Normally, the values would be generated dynamically. But in an attempt to figure out what is causing my query to fail, I hard-coded the values into the query itself. Here's what happens:

1) Using IE, the query runs just fine and inserts a record with all the values as they should be.

2) Using any other browser, the query runs just fine, except that the 'yahh' value is not inserted! All the other values are inserted as they should be.

3) If I copy and paste the query into phpMyAdmin, the query runs just fine, and inserts all the values (including 'yahh').

No matter how I run the query, no errors are reported.

This is the most bizarre bug I have ever seen. I have no idea what could be causing this. It seems like the browser should have nothing to do with it!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Michael Can you show the structure of your table headers?

Comment: IE doesn't run the code. It's executed server-side.

Comment: you don't ask your mysql for the errors, thus no errors are reported. Always run all your queries this way `$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query);`

Comment: I just turned on error reporting. I only get an error when using any browser OTHER than IE: PHP Notice: Undefined index: searched in /home/mikey/public_html/ask2.php on line 3

Comment: @Michael, you won't get a useful answer until you post a complete code snippet that reproduces the issue. How can get advice about `Undefined index: searched` if you don't even tell us what it looks like?

Comment: 'searched' is the name of the problem field. I'm not sure what this error means, or why it doesn't occur when I use IE or paste the query into phpMyAdmin?!

Comment: The code snippet is in my post!

Comment: Your code snippet is fine; something else in your page code is breaking. Can you narrow it down to the simplest example that still shows up the problem? Because I'm guessing that just trying to do that will show you what's going wrong...

Comment: @Michael - Nothing in your code can trigger the `Undefined index: searched` notice. Whatever line #2 of `/home/mikey/public_html/ask2.php` contains, it isn't one of the two lines of code you've posted. Believe it or not, exact code matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines of code alone should work fine.

What's likely happening is that you have some code elsewhere, running before the query, that relies on a browser feature (inspecting the user-agent string, cookie handling, query string, headers, etc.) which is causing this code to misbehave.

If you post more code, like the whole source for the file you're working on, the problem can be more easily revealed.

Answer (score 0):

My crystal ball suggests that you have an element like this in your form:

```
<input type="image" name="searched" value="foo">
```

... and later on you process it like this:

```
$sql .= $_POST['searched'];
```

Internet Explorer has a known issue with `image` input fields:

http://www.kilbot.com.au/2008/05/03/using-the-image-input-type-to-post-a-form-in-ie/

I'm afraid that you need to change your form layout. See the above link for some ideas.